# Powershell: convert System.Object to plain string

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-sqlcmd

i'm trying to retrieve some information from SQL server and assign it to a variable:

```
$query = "select top 1 * from [DB1].[dbo].[table1] where servername='ABC-CDE-SVR1'" 
$svrParams = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance "ADMNSVR"
```

in this case `$svrParams` is a *System.Object* with a bunch of parameters:

```
:\> $svrParams

ServerCode             : 6
ServerName             : ABC-CDE-SVR1
Environment_Abbr       : SVR1
ServerWithInstanceFlag : False
EnvironmentTypeCode    : 3
ActiveFlag             : True
PrimaryDriveLetter     : Z:
```

I'm trying to pull them one by one by assigning to new variables like this:

```
$backupDrive = $svrParams.PrimaryDriveLetter | Out-String
```

The issue is that the variable still comes out *System.Object* type. So when i'm trying to concatenate it with another string, i get 2-line result:

```
:\> $DBbackupLocation = "$backupDrive" + "\Backup\Data\"
:\> $DBbackupLocation 

Z:
\Backup\Data\
```

Please let me know if there is a way to extract the plain text out of the object. Tried [string] before the variable with the same result.

Comment: $svrParams.PrimaryDriveLetter.ToString()

Comment: @richard345 thank you that helped!

Comment: You're welcome! Just a caution, that will fail if PrimaryDriveLetter is ever null.

Comment: Chances are that either `$srvParams` or the `PrimaryDriveLetter` are an array where one or more item is null or whitespace. `[string]$DBbackupDrive = $srvParams.PrimaryDriveLetter|?{![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_)}` That would probably fix the issue.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that's a valid point, will take it into account. thank you